# Do all browsers support loading Javascript json (*.js) files from the "local file system"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, browser, cross-browser

I want to put json structures into javascript ".js" library files, not ".json" files, and load them as needed, from local file storage.

Assuming I'm using jquery, do all browsers fully support being able to load JSON library files from local storage (i.e. not having to go back to the server), via code like:

```
$.getScript("data-one.js", function(){
  // Here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
});
```

I know that CSV files are not supported by all browsers but I'm wondering if loading JSON files is fully supported.

If all browser do, is the code I have above the best way to do so, or is there better code?

If not, why not?

Comment: Making Ajax requests to local files can only work if the document is loaded from the file system, and even then, most browsers disable Ajax for local files by default. And JSON is not JavaScript.

Comment: *"I want to put json structures into ".js" library files, not ".json" files."* JSON is not valid JS, you can't do that. If you mean to do something like `var data = { ... };` then your working with JavaScript objects, not JSON. Either way, documents loaded from the WWW can't access local files (automatically). You can ask the user to provide a file though.

Comment: Yes, I want to use another program to generate and put Javascript structures into "local" *.js library files and then load them into the browser from the local file system, as needed.  It seems to work but I don't know if it's something that's consistently supported by all browsers. Thx.